# How do you implement neurons in ANN?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

From what I understand about Neural Networks, you have a number of hidden layers which each consist of X neurons. A neuron takes in a number of inputs and prospective weights, then using an activation function (sigmoid in my case) gives an output.

My task is to implement a network from scratch (only using numpy), with 2 hidden layers, sigmoid activation function and 500 neurons in each hidden layer. What I don't understand is, how can I implement the concept of neurons? According to [this](https://becominghuman.ai/understanding-neural-networks-1-the-concept-of-neurons-287be36d40f) article, one neuron is when all inputs are weighted and are passed into the activation function. So do I feed in the same inputs, 500 times, with different weights each time (in the first layers, then again in the second)? I've also read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241888/what-are-neurons-in-neural-networks-how-do-they-work/241904) topic, where the following is said:

> The neuron is nothing more than a set of inputs, a set of weights, and an activation function. The neuron translates these inputs into a single output, which can then be picked up as input for another layer of neurons later on.

So according to this, I indeed should weigh the inputs differently, 500 times, and then pass these forward to the next layer which will do the same. Am I understanding this correctly?

Here is the code I have written so far (it is very elementary but I did not want to proceed further before I clear this up), but have no idea how I would be implementing this:

```
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, data, y, neurons, hidden):
        self.input = data
        self.y = y
        self.output = np.zeros(y.shape)
        self.layers = hidden
        self.neurons = neurons
        self.weights = self.generateWeightArray()
        print(self.weights)

    def generateWeightArray(self):
        weightarr = []
        #Last weight array is for inbetween hidden and output layer
        for i in range(self.layers + 1):
            weightarr.append(self.generateWeightMatrix())
        return np.asarray(weightarr)

    def generateWeightMatrix(self):
        return np.random.rand(self.input.shape[0], self.input.shape[1]-1)

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

    def dsigmoid(self, x):
        return self.sigmoid(x)*(1-self.sigmoid(x))

    def train(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        #Since between each layer we have a matrix of weights, we can just keep going for the number of hidden 
        #layers we have
        for i in range(self.layers):
            out = np.dot(self.input.transpose(), self.weights[i]).transpose() #step1
            self.input = self.sigmoid(out) #step2

        print(self.input)

net = NeuralNetwork(np.array([[1,2,3,4],[3,5,1,2],[5,6,7,8]]), np.array([1,0,1]), 500, 2)
net.run()
```

EDIT

I have changed my code as follows

```
class NeuralNetwork:
def __init__(self, data, y, neurons, hidden):
    self.input = data
    self.y = y
    self.output = np.zeros(y.shape)
    self.layers = hidden
    self.neurons = neurons
    self.weights_to_hidden = np.random.rand(self.neurons, self.input.shape[1])
    self.weights = self.generateWeightArray()
    self.weights_to_output = np.random.rand(self.neurons,1)
    print(self.weights_to_output)

#Generate a matrix with h+1 weight matrices, where h is the number of hidden layers (+1 for output)
def generateWeightArray(self):
    weightarr = []
    #Last weight array is for inbetween hidden and output layer
    for i in range(self.layers):
        weightarr.append(self.generateWeightMatrix())
    return np.asarray(weightarr)

#Generate a matrix with n columns and m rows, where n is the number of features and m is the number of neurons
#in the layer
def generateWeightMatrix(self):
    return np.random.rand(self.neurons, self.neurons)

def sigmoid(self, x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def dsigmoid(self, x):
    return self.sigmoid(x)*(1-self.sigmoid(x))

def train(self):
    #2 hidden layers, then hidden -> output layer
    hidden_in = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.input, self.weights_to_hidden.transpose()).transpose())
    print("Going into hidden layer:")
    print(hidden_in)
    for i in range(self.layers):
        in_hidden = self.sigmoid(np.dot(hidden_in.transpose(), self.weights[i]).transpose())
        print("After ",str(i+1), " hidden layer:")
        print(in_hidden)

    print("Output")
    out = self.sigmoid(np.dot(hidden_in.transpose(), self.weights_to_output).transpose())
    print(out)

net = NeuralNetwork(np.array([[1,2,3,4],[3,5,1,2],[5,6,7,8]]), np.array([1,0,1]), 5, 2)
net.train()
```

And the output after running is

> [[0.89405222 0.89501672 0.89717842]]

I'm not sure if `self.weights_to_output` has the correct shape though because its a `(n,1)`, so all features (in each record) will have the same weight, rather than having 3 weights for each row (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'neurons' (usually called 'units' these days) are the activations in each layer. These are represented as a vector with one element for each unit. You will represent a layer's activations as a 1D array. **So the short answer is that the neurons are elements in 1D arrays.**

Let's look at the activation of one unit in layer 3 of a deep neural network:

```
a_3 = sigma(w_3 @ a_2 + b_3)
```

So:

- `a_3` will be a scalar — the activation for this unit;
- `sigma` is the activation function (e.g. logistic function, tanh, or ReLU)
- `w_3` is the vector of weights for *this* layer (one element for each unit of layer 2)
- `a_2` is the vector of activations for the *previous* layer (one element for each unit of layer 2)
- `b_3` is the bias for this unit.

Note that `w_3` and `a_2` are both 1D arrays (vectors). The `@` operator does matrix multiplication in Python 3.4+ and in this case it's going to perform the dot product.

Now, thanks to the magic of linear algebra, it turns out we don't need to loop over each unit to compute all the activations. If we let the weight vector `w_3` be a matrix, `W_3` (note the capital letter), then it can represent the weights for all units in layer 2, connecting to all units in layer 3. Then:

```
a_3 = sigma(W_3 @ a_2 + b_3)
```

Now `a_3` will be a vector.

The tricky part is keeping track of all the shapes. For `W @ a` to work, the shapes must be compatible. For example, imagine we have a network with 2 units in layer 2 (so `a_2` is a 1D array with 2 elements) and 3 units in layers 3 (so `a_3` needs to have 3 elements). Now `W_3` needs to be 3 × 2 and `a_2` needs to be 2 × 1. Then the matrix multiply works. You can just use `np.reshape()` and `np.transpose()` to achieve the shapes you need.

I hope this helps... it's a lot of words.

Maybe this diagram (from [this article](https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Neural_networks)) helps explain:

[image: simepl neural net]

The diagram doesn't say how many records there are. There are 3 features per data instance (i.e. we have an *M* × 3 input matrix). The input layer is 'just' another layer, you can think of the inputs as just another set of activations. You could think of `x` as `a_0` (the 0-th layer).

This 3 Blue 1 Brown video is well worth watching too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk

Comment: What I am still having trouble understanding, is the following. I have 3 input vectors, each with 4 features, called i0, i1, i2. These are all 1x4 vectors. For simplicity's sake, I have one hidden layer with 5 neurons. Then, its weight matrix will be 5x4 (5 rows, 4 columns), because each feature has an individual weight, but we are doing the computation once for each neuron. Is this right? I'm getting very confused by this despite drawing it out too!

Comment: Or I suspect that the weight matrices must change, depending on which layer we are moving to, so I worked out the following: `weight_to_hidden` must have a size of `(n, k)`, with `n` neurons and `k` length input vectors. Then, we must have a weight matrix for each hidden layer, which has a size of `(n,n)`. This means that the initial `k` component input vectors get compressed into `m` numbers (for `m` number of inputs), which means that dotting against `(n,n)` size matrix results a `(m, k)` matrix. Am i on the right lines now?

Comment: So in the proposed scenario, we have `n = 5` neurons, `k = 4` features in each input, `m = 3` input vectors. So the `input` is `(3,4)`, `weight_to_hidden` is a `(5,4)` matrix, so dotted (`weight_to_hidden T`) the result is `(3,5)`, which goes into the first hidden layer. In the hidden layer, `input_to_hidden.transpose()` dotted against the `(5,5)` (and then transposed) will result `(3,5)` again. This seems plausible to me

Comment: If you are talking about the diagram I posted, then... almost. Just think about one data instance (one record, i.e. one row in your input matrix). The diagram doesn't say how many records there are. There are 3 features. The input layer is 'just' another layer, you can think of the inputs as just another set of activations.

Comment: Sorry, I guess you might be talking about your specific example, except that there are 4 features in yours, compared to 3 in my figure. Either way, I think you're getting there... but just note that, if you're processing one record at a time, then *only* `W` is a 2D array, everything else (`x`, `a`, `b`) is a 1D array.

Comment: Im not sure if processing one record at a time is feasible though; in my real dataset I have 1000 rows, with 12 features each (and an output), which in all fairness I probably have to split into batches. Either way, please see my edit to see what I mean; I'm still a bit confused but Im fairly confident I got it until the very last part (last hidden layer -> output)

Comment: I would process one record at a time, at least until things work. Then you can worry about batches. The output layer is just another layer. If you're doing regression, it has one unit. If you're doing classification, it has one unit for a binary problem, or _c_ units for a problem with _c_ > 2 classes (and a softmax activation function, not whatever you have on the other layers).

Comment: I got to the point where things work. However I am struggling to understand how I can properly train the model if I feed it one record at a time (all weights would just be overwritten once the training is finished for one record), or alternatively, how my structure should be for multiple records at one given time. Your answer is for one record only :/